# Why would the stroma have a higher pH during photosynthesis?

Tags: photosynthesis

Here is a question form my test.

> If you could measure the pH of the interior of thylakoids and the
>   surrounding stroma during active photosynthesis what would be the
>   relative pH of each?

The answer is C.

> the stroma would have a higher pH

I understand that proton gradient is from stroma to thylakoid space, but that does not mean stroma would have less protons than thylakoid space, if stroma would have a higher pH, then the proton will never flow from stroma to thylakoid space, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Energy from an electron transport chain is used to actively transport protons from the stroma to the thylakoid lumen. Thus the lumen has a relatively higher proton concentration and therefore a lower pH than the stroma.

Higher [H<sup>+</sup>] means lower pH.

Lower [H<sup>+</sup>] means higher pH.

Keep in mind that the flow of actively transported protons from the stroma to the lumen is against their concentration gradient. There wouldn't be a net flow of protons this way without active transport.